# Why am I loosing saved user queries in Arango AQL Editor UI?

Tags: arangodb

Is it possible that queries can get lost if you use the Web UI in several tabs?
I think this happens from time to time, but I still can't reproduce it always:
I open two tabs und use the AQL Editor in both, create two *different* queries and store them in two *different query names. It seems to be somehow random if and which one really get stored in the user collection.

Is there a saver way to use the AQL editor in parallel? Is it maybe possible to check for the query name while storing it or something like this?

Answer (score 8):

I can confirm this misbehaviour.

We have adjusted the AQL Editor to synchronise its queries every time when reading/writing operations are necessary.

It is fixed in our current development branch and will be shipped with the upcoming version 2.4.4.